# Disable zoomin in iOS (webpages)

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I'm trying to disable the zoom in when users clicks on input (iOS). I've tried a lot of things like:

Force font-size to 16px;
Modify viewport `user-scalable=no`

It seems that anything works in the latest version of iOS.

Could you help me?

Thank you!

EDIT: I would like to allow the user to do zoom if they want. I want to prevent the auto automatic zoom when user clicks on input.

Answer (score 0):

Try [viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) in head:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```